# fillPolly() and drawContours() not working - Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing and I cant get `fillPoly()` working. Also, `drawContours()` is leaving some spaces while drawing contours. I am working on Android and most of the references that are given on internet are of Python, Matlab or C++

```
   sSize5 = new Size(5, 5);


    mIntermediateMat = new Mat();

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.contours_in_contours_red);

    Mat rgba = new Mat(bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, rgba);

    Mat greyInnerWindow;
    greyInnerWindow = new Mat();

    Mat mRgba = new Mat();


    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, greyInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(greyInnerWindow, greyInnerWindow, sSize5, 2, 2);


    Imgproc.Canny(greyInnerWindow, mIntermediateMat, 5, 35);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);



    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();

    Imgproc.findContours(mIntermediateMat, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,
            Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
        Imgproc.drawContours(rgba, contours, i, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1);

        Imgproc.fillPoly(rgba, contours, new Scalar(0,255,0));

    }
    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgba.cols(), rgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(rgba, resultBitmap);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

[image: This is the image on which I am using fillPoly() and drawContours()]

[image: This is after using the above code]

[image]

[image]

Comment: post sample images please. Are you sure your contours are closed correctly?

Comment: sorry, hard to see anything on those tiny images. Can you test your code with an artifical image with clear contours like: https://picload.org/image/raalllaa/contours_in_contours_red.png maybe change the color of your drawn contours to green for that test :)

Comment: @Micka: No problem, I have removed submat() function from the code and also tried the image you gave and posted result hee by editing the question